# Find the projection p of x onto the span of u1 and u2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

where $u_1=(2/3, 2/3, 1/3)$ and $u_2=(1/\sqrt2, -1/\sqrt2, 0)$ and $x=(1,2,2)$

how do I find the span of $u_1$ and $u_2$? after that do I just use the formula for the vector projection of x onto the span?

Comment: Last minute homework, I sense.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$The projection of $\\x$ onto $span(\\u_1,\\u_2)$ is
$$(\\x\cdot \\u_1)\\u_1+(\\x\cdot \\u_2)\\u_2\ .$$
But **note** that this only works because $\\u_1$ and $\\u_2$ are orthonormal vectors.